# Django: Pass paramter to view funciton, but not in url

Tags: django

What I'm trying to do is allow my login page to be told whether to show an alert by through reverse without using the url from a redirect from another view function.

My login view function looks like:

```py
def login(request, alert=False):
    ...
    context = generate_basic_context(request)
    if (alert):
        context['alert'] = {
            'type': 'danger',
            'text': 'You need to be logged in to do that!'
        }
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

My urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('login/', views.login, {'alert': False}, name='login'),
    ...
]
```

And my reverse (function is called from other view functions):

```py
def makeauthenticate():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login', kwargs={'alert': True'}))
```

Error: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' with keyword arguments '{'alert': True}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/login/$']`

Comment: You don't. Since the parameters passed to the function are extracted from the path of the URL.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is there any possible way I can do something similar to this?

Comment: there are several ways to pass data to a view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358329/67579 but except for sessions, most submit data through the request. This is also how it *should* be done, since a GET should be stateless according to the HTTP specifications.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for your help. Have a good day!